# SOAP client over SSL: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, client-certificates

I am working with remoted SOAP service through the HTTPS (HTTP over SSL) and I've generated my client classes with axis `WSDL2java` tool. So, I use Axis2 client, i have tried Axis too, here wasn't difference between them 
I have selfmade certificate in .pfx just for developing.
First I've tried to make request through the SoapUI, and i just add my certificate and password in SSLsettings:

[image]

And that works fine.

After that I've tried to make request with my Axis client  through the Java code. Before sending request I've added:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\work\example.pfx");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "myPassw");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider", "SunJSSE");
```

After that I sent request with my client:

```
SMTHExample_ServiceStub client = 
new SMTHExample_ServiceStub("https://ipaddr:10443/anotherpartOfUrl");
Info2Resp gi2resp = client.getResp2(getSmth2);
```

And after that i got an exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>       sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
>       sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
>       certification path to requested target

After that i've tried to run my class with SoapUI's jre, but it didn't help, I got exactly the same error.

I also tried to use different workarounds like `org.apache.axis2.java.security.TrustAllTrustManager` to disregard the certificate and trust the server, but they didn't help too.

Launching the Client with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,keymanager` show in both cases:

```
keyStore is : C:\work\example.pfx
keyStore type is : PKCS12
keyStore provider is : SunJSSE
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
...here going init... 
trustStore is: path/to/jre/lib/security/cacerts/mine/or/SoapUI's
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
...here are added all trusted certs...
```

And I don't  know is it important but after adding certs I saw in log:

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

And after all, as I understand, during the handshake i got in log

```
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: You should add server certificate to trustStore (set javax.net.ssl.trustStore parameter or add it to cacerts or manually set SSLContext) keyStore parameter used for client  certificates. See docs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/sslthin.htm#BABCBGDB

Comment: @user1516873 Owners of webservice gave me 2 files: .pfx and .cer, also they gave me passw from .pfx. I've added .cer certificate to cacerts and left other settings as were before. But it doesn't help. And another question: why does  it work in soapUI(even without  link to .cer file)?

Comment: Maybe Soap UI it skip some validations? It is up to client check server certificate, so it can just pass it on. Better to ask different question in `soapui` tag. Java do validation and expected to find CA who issued current certificate, check certificate revocation and valid from/to dates and check site name equals to value of CN field. You can disable certificate check, but i strongly advise not to do it - that make possible MITM attack.